# Can not log into the ftp server with authenticated users

Tags: ftp

I have setup the ftp server locally,I created authenticated users to access the ftp server.

I want to give privileges such as delete,write,read to the users.
I followed lot of tutorials, but still couldn't log in to the ftp server.
Here's below changes I have done

remove comment in following lines in /etc/vsftpd.conf

```
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
```

added users to `/etc/vsftp.chroot_list file`

then

```
sudo touch /etc/vsftp.chroot_list
```

finally restarted the server, but I can't login to the ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check port 21 is listening with below command. If you have customized port then replace 21 with that port number.

> netstat -pan | grep 21

If it is listening then check if you can ftp locally:

> ftp localhost

and then stop firewall for some time from your server and then try again.